# Issue retrieving keys and values from nested JSON object

Tags: java, json, wordpress, api

I need help retrieving the keys and values of this nested `JSON`. It is a `JSON` object of multiple values wrapped in another `JSON` object that is finally wrapped in an array. See an example of what I'm talking about

[image: See what I'm referring to]

I've used several codes but don't work.

Like

```
org.json.JSONObject jsonFile = new org.json.JSONObject(_response);
        org.json.JSONObject key = jsonFile.getJSONObject("x_metadata");

test1 = key.getString("wp_GP_ID");
```

See Image Here:

[image: See Image Here]

I'm using the WordPress rest API so I'll be glad if anyone can assist me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the Jackson json processor, it's simple and intuitive.

here is a example.

```
//json string to JsonNode
String data = "{\"x_metadata\": {\"key_1\": \"text1\"," +
        " \"key_2\": true, \"key_3\": 100.0," +
        " \"key_array\": [\"text array 1\", \"text array 2\"]}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(data);
System.out.println(node);

//get object x_metadata
JsonNode nodeMetadata = node.get("x_metadata");
System.out.println(nodeMetadata);

//get value of a key
String valueKey = nodeMetadata.get("key_1").asText();
System.out.println(valueKey);

//get key type
System.out.println(nodeMetadata.getNodeType());
System.out.println(nodeMetadata.get("key_2").getNodeType());
System.out.println(nodeMetadata.get("key_3").getNodeType());
System.out.println(nodeMetadata.get("key_array").getNodeType());

//get keys
nodeMetadata.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

pom.xml dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

here more info about Jackson:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks alot. But do you have or happen to know any other method apart from jackson

Comment: Gson is another library can help you. https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide.
here a comparison, https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson